# Difference between TWO approaches to create a ZIP file

Tags: c#, dotnetzip, fileinfo

In my application, I need to convert the file which is dropped by user to a ZIP file, in a temporary folder. I am using **DotNetZip** for this purpose by writing something like this.

```
zip.AddFile("DroppedFile.xyz");
zip.Save("C:\\Temp\MyZip.zip");
```

I was able to achieve the same by creating a `FileInfo` type and using the `CopyTo` method by writing the below code.

```
FileInfo myfile = new FileInfo("C:\\DroppedFile.xyz");
myfile.CopyTo("C:\\Temp\MyZip.zip");
```

I get the same result, both create a ZIP file in the temp directory. But what I want to know is that is there something like I shouldn't use the second approach because I feel it is not being used for its intended purpose (Correct me if I'm wrong). Please let me know the difference between both the approaches.

Comment: Have you tried unzipping the file created by the second approach??

Comment: Also, read `FileInfo.CopyTo` documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I did unzip and it is fine. :)

Comment: Try again. At least the ZIP programs I have refuse to open the "zip file" created with the second method. Also, check the compression rate/file size of the "zip file" created with the second method. Tip: The second method just renames the file; it does not do anything to create an actual ZIP file.

Comment: Tried with WinRar and WinZip, both went fine. Yeah it actually does renaming only. The zip file is exactly of the size of the original file.